# I have AWS API gateway in which it is integrating with lambda function through body mapping template

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rds

I have AWS API gateway in which it is integrating with lambda function through body mapping template  as below

```
{
 "bid":"$input.params('bid')"
}
```

Now i have to take "bid" variable to below lambda python function and should use as  a query

```
import sys
import logging
import pymysql
import json
rds_host="rds.amazonaws.com"
name="name"
password="pass"
db_name=""
port = 3306
def save_events(event):
result = []
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=, passwd=, db=, connect_timeout=30)
with conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cur:
cur.execute("select exid,exercise_name,image from exercise where bid = 3")
result = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
print ("Data from RDS...")
print (result)
workout = json.dumps(result)
workouts=(workout.replace("\"", "'"))
def lambda_handler(event, context):
save_events(event)
return workouts
```

Now how should I add "bid" from API to this lambda and modify the query dynamically using "bid"

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
bid = event["bid"]
```

Your code become:

```
import sys
import logging
import pymysql
import json
rds_host="rds.amazonaws.com"
name="name"
password="pass"
db_name=""
port = 3306
def save_events(bid):
  result = []
  conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=, passwd=, db=, connect_timeout=30)
  with conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cur:
  cur.execute("select exid,exercise_name,image from exercise where bid = " + bid)
  result = cur.fetchall()
  cur.close()
  print ("Data from RDS...")
  print (result)
  workout = json.dumps(result)
  workouts=(workout.replace("\"", "'"))
  return workouts

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  workouts = save_events(event["bid"])
  return workouts
```